# Python Imblearn - How to track original data records

Tags: python, unbalanced-classes

My data is severely unbalanced, so I'm using Python imbalanced-learn here to make data balanced: https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.combine.SMOTEENN.html#imblearn.combine.SMOTEENN

After model prediction, I also need to know how many original labels got predicted right, but now I'm having difficulty to track the original labels after data sampling.

Because:

1. My id for each row is categorical data. Sampling functions only accept numerical data. If I convert it into float, these ids can also be duplicated and then I won't know which is the original id.
2. There are exactly same rows (if we ignore row id), so I cannot simply using all the features to identify a row
3. I have also checked, after data sampling, imblearned will add samples in between original data. So, I cannot find which row is the original row.

**Is there anyway to track original data and labels after oversampling methods?** Python or R should both be fine.

Comment: You should NOT be applying SMOTE to your test data, so this really shouldn't be an issue if you're doing things properly.

Comment: True, I also plan to make this change. But I'm still required to check those in training data...